# How can I check links in HTML files?

Tags: html, validation, hyperlink

I found a [list of tools](http://www.smartinsights.com/search-engine-optimisation-seo/link-building/site-link-checking-tools/) to check web sites but what if I haven't deployed yet?  What if the collection of `.htm[l]` files is just sitting on my local disk?

Comment: What exactly do you want to check? In general you can always set up yourself a dynamic DNS account which provides your local server with a static IP which is reachable from the web.

Comment: Why not to use some of that tools (say, that Chrome plugin) to check links on you local site?

Comment: I don't have a *site*. These files are really input used to build .chm help. But it seems easier to run some link checker on them than to go through the whole build process and have the help compiler give me errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the html file in your browser of choice.  The links should still take you to the appropriate location but the url might not be active since your website is not live.  This is a manual way to do it at least.

There may be a more automated way that I do not know of.  Hope this helps.

SHORT DIRECTIONS:
Select the file and right click choosing open with...

Choose your web browser and it should open the file in your browser.

**Using the tools you linked will be faster most likely**

Just follow the directions in your link and read the documentation/manual.  They are usually meant to be non technical.  Especially the chrome one.

Comment: There is megabytes of data in 700+ pages; manual validation isn't really an option.

Comment: Why dont you run a dummy (local) server on your local machine and use the corresponding add on for your web browser.  Chrome would be [Check my links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/check-my-links/ojkcdipcgfaekbeaelaapakgnjflfglf?hl=en-GB).  I know django allows for your web page to run in test mode on localhost:8000 and is in turn able to be brought up in Chrome.